# How do i re-render the page without reloading, after submition?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I'm new in MERN. I need help to re-render the page after i submit. Let me clarify!!

After Admin creates a task, it successfully saves in database but to see the change in client side, I have to either navigate to another page and come back or f5 the page. The form where admin creates a task is a popup. Is there any solution that after admin creates a task, it automatically re-renders the page again.

Here is my createTask page:

```
function Task() {
  // const redirect = useNavigate();
  const [getUserData, setUserdata] = useState([]);
  const [openPopup, setOpenPopup] = useState(false);

  const getData = async (e) => {
    const res = await fetch("/createtask", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
    });

    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
    if (res.status === 404 || !data) {
      alert("error");
      console.log("error");
    } else {
      setUserdata(data);
      // console.log("Get Data");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    <Sidebar/>
      <div className="tskms_task_mid">
        <div className="tskms_task_mid-top">
          <h2>Tasks</h2>
          <Button
            id="createtask"
            variant="contained"
            onClick={() => setOpenPopup(true)}
          >
            Create Task
          </Button>
        </div>
```

this is my popup.js

```
function Popup(props) {
  const history = useNavigate();
  const { openPopup, setOpenPopup } = props;
  const [employeeName, setEmployeeName] = useState({
    taskName: "",
    assignTo: "",
    startedOn: new Date(),
    dueDate: new Date(),
    taskDescription: "",
    requiredFiles: "",
  });

  const clgdata = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setEmployeeName((newData) => {
      return { ...newData, [name]: value };
    });
  };

  const changeStartDate = (newValue) => {
    setEmployeeName((prev) => {
      return { ...prev, startedOn: newValue };
    });
  };

  const changeDueDate = (newValue) => {
    setEmployeeName((prev) => {
      return { ...prev, dueDate: newValue };
    });
  };
  const createTask = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {
      taskName,
      assignTo,
      startedOn,
      dueDate,
      taskDescription,
      requiredFiles,
    } = employeeName;
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/createtask", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        taskName,
        assignTo,
        startedOn,
        dueDate,
        taskDescription,
        requiredFiles,
      }),
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
    if (res.status === 404 || !data) {
      alert("Please Complete the Empty Fields");
    } else {
      alert(`Task has been assigned to the employee`);
      setOpenPopup(false);
      history("/task");
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Dialog open={openPopup}>
        <DialogTitle>
          <div className="title">
            <ArrowBackIcon
              className="leftArrow"
              onClick={() => setOpenPopup(false)}
            >
              close
            </ArrowBackIcon>

            <h3>Create a task</h3>
          </div>
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <div className="form">
            <TextField
              className="form-btn"
              name="taskName"
              type="text"
              id="outlined-basic"
              label="Task Title"
              variant="outlined"
              onChange={clgdata}
              value={employeeName.taskName}
            />
            <TextField
              sx={{ mb: 1 }}
              name="assignTo"
              type="text"
              onChange={clgdata}
              value={employeeName.assignTo}
              className="form-btn"
              id="outlined-basic"
              label="Select an Employee"
            ></TextField>
            <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
              <Stack spacing={1}>
                <DatePicker
                  sx={{ m: 4 }}
                  name="startedOn"
                  minDate={new Date()}
                  className="form-btn startedOn"
                  label="Started On"
                  type="date"
                  value={employeeName.startedOn}
                  onChange={changeStartDate}
                  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                />
                <DatePicker
                  className="startedOff"
                  minDate={new Date()}
                  id="dueDate"
                  name="dueDate"
                  label="Due Date"
                  value={employeeName.dueDate}
                  onChange={changeDueDate}
                  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                />

                <TextField
                  sx={{ mb: 1}}
                  className="form-btn"
                  id="outlined-basic"
                  label="Task Description"
                  variant="outlined"
                  name="taskDescription"
                  type="text"
                  onChange={clgdata}
                  value={employeeName.taskDescription}
                />
              </Stack>
            </LocalizationProvider>
            <TextField
              sx={{ mb: 1 }}
              className="form-btn"
              id="outlined-basic"
              label="Required Files"
              variant="outlined"
              name="requiredFiles"
              type="text"
              onChange={clgdata}
              value={employeeName.requiredFiles}
            />
          </div>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={createTask}>Submit</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </>
  );
}

export default Popup;
```

Comment: May I know why you want to want to reload the page? Is it because you want to clear the form input values?

Comment: I think you have to set data on client side and backend side after you called an api, so you can see client side updated data, let me know if need example

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {
     getData();
  }, []);
```

This only executes once after the first render because the dependency array passed is empty.
You can re-run the `useEffect` by passing a state variable into the dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {//Executes every time someState changes
     getData();
  }, [someState]);
```

Then you can `setSomeState` when you successfully post new data.